# Deleting the Normal Template in MS Word 2019

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2019

I need to delete the Normal template in Word 2019.
I tried following MicroSoft's directions found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-normal-template-normal-dotm-06de294b-d216-47f6-ab77-ccb5166f98ea
In Word, after I click File>Open, here's what I see:
[Screenshot of Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEk89.jpg)
I don't know where to enter what MicroSoft recommends for Step 2.
I've tried a general search of my computer for normal.dot and nothing came up.

Comment: Check the folder C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates to find normal.dotm. Change YourUserName to match your username.

Comment: Here is my page with directions on how to find the Normal template. http://addbalance.com/word/normaltemplate.htm#Find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explorer to position to the folder
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`.

Move the two `.dotm` files elsewhere and start Word.
This will recreate the templates.

If everything works right, you may delete those files that you copied.

Answer (score 0):

The Step 2 means you need to go to File Explorer.

Please close all the files of Office and go to File explorer > View in Show/hide group > check the box of "Hidden Items".

Go to `C:\Users\<user name >\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`, then find the Normal.dotm and rename it. This file will be automatically generated when reopen Word.

Besides, you could also enter %Appdata% in Windows Search box.

[image]

Then contine to find the global template Normal.dotm.

[image]